# Why do you need to place an 'f' at the end of the decimal number when declaring a float variable?

Tags: java

I have seen this question asked before. However, I am not satisfied with the answers that are given. Typical responses are that Java sees the number as a double, since that is the default in JAVA, and gives a mismatch error on compiling.

This behavior is apparently totally ignoring my use of a float declaration.

My question is: If I am declaring a variable type as `float`, why does Java think it is a double? I am specifically declaring:

```
float x = 3.14;
```

I have told Java that I want this variable to be a float type by using the float keyword. Why is this required?

```
float x = 3.14f;
```

If I want a double type variable, I use the double keyword specifically declaring the variable as a double.

```
double x = 3.14;
```

Why does Java not recognize this when declaring a variable and insists the literal needs to be cast from a double to a float by adding the 'f' at the end? Shouldn't Java recognize the use of the keyword `float` and properly assign the type to the literal?

Comment: Bear in mind that the value on the right of the assignment is not the same thing as the variable on the left of the assignment. It's possible in lots of circumstances to assign a value of one type to a variable of another type. Just not in this case. Java could *assume* that you mean a float value because you declared a float variable in some cases; or rather than assuming, it could let you know of a possible problem so you can make sure you specify what you actually mean.

Comment: To rephrase @khelwood comment: You have told JAVA that you want the value to be STORED as a float, but the value after the equal sign could technically be of any reasonable type.  The compiler (or interpreter in the case of Java) has the duty to convert your value 3.14 to the type specified (float).  By design, JAVA will interpret any unclassified value that "looks like" a double, as a double.

Comment: I think the following link maybe the answer you are looking for. 
https://www.quora.com/Why-would-you-append-an-F-to-the-end-of-a-value-of-a-floating-point-literal-in-Java-e-g-float-ratio-0-2363F-Isnt-that-already-specified-in-the-data-type-float-What-happens-if-I-dont-include-the-f-Do-something-similar-happens-in-the-integer-data-types

Comment: Consider the differences beween `float a = 1f`, `float b = 1` and `float c = 1.0`
the righthand side value is float, int and double.
then those will be massaged (casted) to fit into the desired variable type, namely float.
first one is fine, second and third one will introduce innacuracy.

Comment: @Shark The second one will also work just fine, because that is a widening primitive conversion.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i'm not saying it's not going to work, but there has to exist an integer literal that doesn't quite map precisely to a float. 1 is probably a bad example, but if we take any 3byte number literal, e.g. `0xF << 24` it will introduce inaccuracies because a float only uses 23bits for mantisa, 8 for exponent and 1 for sign. when you widen that (if there is going to be any widening) you might not end up with `251658240` but something very close to it. right?

Comment: @Shark Yes, but the second one of your example will work (because it is a widening primitive conversion), while the third of the example will not work (because it is a narrowing primitive conversion).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel fair enough, point taken, i should have put more effort into demonstrating with a better (counter-) example such as by using 251658240 instead of 1 :)

Comment: @Shark That may lose precision, but still be allowed by the compiler as it is a widening primitive conversion. The problem with `float x = 3.14` is not that it may lose precision, it is that assigning a double to a float is simply not allowed by the compiler as it is a narrowing primitive conversion, unless you add an explicit cast. The compiler is not 'smart' enough to figure out that 3.14 will fit just fine in a float, it just knows that the maximum magnitude of a double will not fit into a float, and therefor deny the assignment.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel right right, there's no arguing that point that every primitive with a decimal is considered a double unless explicitly declared a float by adding `f` to it's end.

Answer (score 10):

## Size matters

32-bit float → `float x = 3.14 ;` ← 64-bit double

The default for a fractional numeric literal in Java is the 64-bit primitive `double` type, as shown in the [Answer by Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66158887/642706). `3.14` is a `double`, as is `3.14d` and `3.14D`.

The primitive `float` type is smaller, 32-bit.

If Java were to infer that what you *said* is a `double` but what you *meant* is a `float`, Java would have to reduce the 64-bit value to a 32-bit value, discarding half the data, 32-bits. This could involve **data loss** for larger numbers. And this would definitely mean a **loss of capacity**.

So the designers of Java decided to be conservative in this matter. They decided to not be so presumptive as to throw away half your data, nor to reduce your specified capacity by half. They decided to take you at your word — if you said 64-bit `double`, they give you a `double`.

If you then go on to say you want to cram that 64-bit number into a 32-bit container, they flag the error, as 64-bits does not fit into 32-bits. Square peg, round hole.

round hole, 32-bit float → `float x = 3.14 ;` ← 64-bit double, square peg

Java does support the converse, a widening conversion. You can put a 32-bit `float` into a 64-bit `double`. And you can put a 32-bit `int` into a 64-bit `long`. These operations are safe, as the extra 32-bits can be filled safely with zeros. So Java is willing and able to support these operations.

## Be explicit

I suggest you make a habit of being explicit. Do not rely on the default. If you mean a 32-bit `float`, append the `f` or `F` to your literal. If you mean a 64-bit `double`, append the `d` or `D` to your literal.

Doing so not only quiets the compiler, it makes your intentions clear to the humans reading your code.

```
float pi = 3.14F ;
double pi = 3.14d ;
```

## `BigDecimal`

And, by the way, if you care about [accuracy rather than performance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems), you’ll be using [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) rather than `float`/`double`. In which case this issue is moot.

```
BigDecimal pi = new BigDecimal( "3.14" ) ;
```

Comment: So, to clarify, saying "float x = 3.14" tells the compiler to stuff a double into a float?

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev Yes. To the right of the `=` is a 64-bit `double`. To the left, a `32-bit` float. As you can see when [running his code live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/6JFT7R), you get an error: *incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float*

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the Java Language Specification specifies that a floating point literal without the `f` or `F` suffix, is a `double`. From [Floating-Point Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) in the Java 15 Language Specification:

> A floating-point literal is of type `float` if it is suffixed with an
> ASCII letter `F` or `f`; otherwise its type is `double` and it can
> optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter `D` or `d`.

Java doesn't try to infer the type of the literal based on the type of the variable you're assigning to. A double-literal is simply always a `double`. In other words, semantically, it behaves the same as if your code did:

```java
double temp = 3.14;
float x = temp;
```

Which will also fail to compile, because assigning a `double` to a `float` can result in loss of information, if the magnitude of the value is too large to fit in a `float`. This is known as [narrowing primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3), and requires an explicit cast to tell the compiler you're aware of the risk and you accept it.

In some cases, it may seem as if Java will perform inference of type from the variable (e.g. when assigning an `int` or `long` literal to a `double` or `float` variable), but that is because the entire range of `int` and `long` can be stored in a `float` or `double` (possibly with loss of precision). This is known as [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).