# Why the need for "F" and "L" suffixes at the end of long and float data types?

Tags: java

Why are the "F" and "L" suffixes needed when declaring a long or float? According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> An integer literal is of type `long` if it ends with the letter `L` or `l`; otherwise it is of type `int`.
> A floating-point literal is of type `float` if it ends with the letter `F` or `f`; otherwise its type is `double`.

So, from that, obviously the compiler is treating the values as either an int data type or a double data type, by default. That doesn't quite explain things for me.

I dug a bit deeper and found a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66158375) where a user describes the conversion from a 64-bit double into a 32-bit float would result in data loss, and the designers didn't want to make assumptions.

Questions I still have:

1. Why would the compiler allow one to write `byte myByte = 100;`, and the compiler automatically convers 100, an int as described above, into a byte, but the compiler won't allow the `long myLong = 3_000_000_000;`? Why will it not auto-convert 3_000_000_000 into a long, despite it being well within the range of a long?
   [image: Error converting 3_000_000_000 into long]
2. As discussed above, when designing Java, the designers won't allow a double to be assigned to a float because of the data loss. While this may be true for a value that is outside of the range of a float, obviously something like 3.14 is small-enough for a float. So then, why does the compiler throw an error with the assignment `float myFloat = 3.14;`?

Ultimately, I'm failing to fully understand why the suffixes are needed, and the rules surrounding automatic casting (if that's what's happening under-the-hood), etc.

I know this topic has been discussed before, but the answers given only raise more questions, so I am deciding to create a new post.

Comment: without f or l how would you specify that a literal is a float or long?

Comment: This might be helpful: [Reasoning behind having to specify L for long, F,D for float, double](//stackoverflow.com/q/7522901)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reasoning behind having to specify L for long, F,D for float, double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522901/reasoning-behind-having-to-specify-l-for-long-f-d-for-float-double)

Comment: No, it doesn't, but it is an interesting read to see the differences in the computation. Thanks for suggesting it.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your specific questions:

1. The problem with `long myLong = 3_000_000_000;` is that `3_000_000_000` is not a legal `int` literal because 3,000,000,000 does not fit into 4 bytes. The fact that you want to promote it to a `long` in order to initialize `myLong` is irrelevant. (Yes, the language designers could have designed the language so that in this context `3_000_000_000` could have been parsed as a `long`, but they didn't, probably to keep the language simpler and to avoid ambiguities in other contexts.)
2. The problem with `3.14` is not a matter of range but of loss of precision. In particular, while 3.14 terminates in base 10 representation, it does not have a finite representation in binary floating point. So converting from a `double` to a `float` (in order to initialize `myFloat`) would involve truncating significant, non-zero bits of the representation. (But just to be clear: Java considers every narrowing conversion from `double` to `float` to be lossy, regardless of the actual values involved. So `float myFloat = 3.0;` would also fail. However, `float myFloat = 3;` succeeds because conversion from an `int` value to a `float` is considered a widening conversion.)

In both cases, the right thing to do is to indicate exactly to the compiler what you are trying to do by appending the appropriate suffix to the numeric literal.

Comment: Why is `100` assignable to a `byte` with neither suffix nor a cast, but not `3_000_000_000` to a `long`?

Comment: @Ted thank you for the answer. I understand the points, and it makes sense. I think one of the problems in fully understanding things is not knowing what's happening "under-the-hood." Is there an assignment taking place behind the scenes when you create an integer literal?

Comment: @JohnKugelman - That is governed by the rules for conversions in an assignment context ([Java Language Specification Section 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)). Specifically, if the value is a compile time constant, "A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable." Note that if the value is not a constant, then narrowing primitive conversions are not allowed at all.

Comment: @kvnr - When you create an integer literal, there's no assignment to anything in your code, but the compiler does parse and store the value somewhere in its data structures. This happens pretty early in the parsing process, before the context is analyzed, so each literal needs to be a legal value without regard to how it's going to be used.

Comment: @TedHopp that makes sense. Know any good resources on where I could go to learn about this parsing process and how the value is being stored? Would be interesting to know.

Comment: @kvnr - Since there is no "official" parser, there is no one answer to that. A good place to start is [this page](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/) maintained by the OpenJDK Compiler Group for the Java programming language. It has links to lots of good resources for your bedtime reading. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Why would the compiler allow one to write byte myByte = 100;, and the compiler automatically convers 100, an int as described above, into a byte, but the compiler won't allow the long myLong = 3_000_000_000;?

Because the spec says so. Note that `byte myByte = 100;` does work, yes, but that is a *special case*, explicitly mentioned in the Java Language Specification; ordinarily, `100` as a literal in a `.java` file is always interpreted as an `int` first, and **never** silently converts itself to a byte, *except* in two cases, both explicitly mentioned in the JLS: The cast is 'implied' in modified assignment: `someByteArr += anyNumber;` always works and implies the cast (again, why? Because the spec says so), and the same explicit presumption is made when declaring a variable: `byte b = 100;`, assuming the int literal is in fact in byte range (-128 to +127).

The JLS does not make an explicit rule that such concepts are applied in a `long x = veryLargeLiteral;`. **And that is where your quest really ought to end**. The spec says so. End of story.

If you'd like to ask the question: "Surely whomever person or persons added this, or rather failed to add this explicit case to the JLS had their reasons for it, and these reasons are more technical and merit based than 'cuz they thought of it in a dream' or 'because they flipped a coin', and then we get to a pure guess (because you'd have to ask them, so probably James Gosling, about why he made a decision 25 years ago):

Because it would be considerably more complex to implement for the `javac` codebase.

Right now literals are first considered as an `int` and only then, much later in the process, if the code is structured such that the JLS says no cast is needed, they can be 'downcast'. Whereas with the long scenario this does not work: Once you try to treat `3_000_000_000` as an int, you already lost the game because that does not fit, thus the parser that parses this needs to create some sort of bizarro 'schrodinger's cat' style node, which represents `3_000_000_000` accurately, but nevertheless will downstream get turned into a parsing error UNLESS it is used in an explicit scenario where the silently-treat-as-long part is allowed. That's certainly possible, but slightly more complex.

Presumably the same argument applies to why, in 25 years, java has not seen an update. It could get that at some point in time, but I doubt it'll have high priority.

> As discussed above, when designing Java, the designers won't allow a double to be assigned to a float because of the data loss.

This really isn't related at all. `int -> long` is lossy, but `double -> float` mostly isn't (it's floating point, you lose a little every time you do stuff with them pretty much, but that's sort of baked into the contract when you use them at all, so that should not stop you).

> obviously something like 3.14 is small-enough for a float.

Long and int are easy: Ints go from about -2 billion to about +2 billion and longs go a lot further. But float/double is not like that. They represent roughly the same range (which is HUGE, 300+ digit numbers are fine), but **their accuracy goes down** as you get away from the 0, and for floats it goes down a lot faster. *Almost every number*, probably including 3.14, **cannot be perfectly represented** by either float or double, so we're just arguing on how much error is acceptable. Thus, java does not as a rule silently convert stuff to a float, because, hey, you picked double, presumably for a reason, so you need to explicitly tell the compiler: "Yup. I get it, I want you to convert and I will accept the potential loss, it is what I want", because once the compiler starts guessing at what you meant, that is an *excellent* source of hard to find bugs. Java has loads of places where it is designed like this. Contrast to languages like javascript or PHP where tons of code is legal even if it is bizarre and seems to make no sense, because the compiler will just try to guess at what you wanted.

Java is much better than that - it draws a line; once your code is sufficiently weird that the odds that javac knows what you wanted drop below a treshold, java will actively refuse to then take a wild stab in the dark at what you meant and will just flat out refuse and ask you to be more clear about it. In a 20 year coding career I cannot stress enough how useful that is :)

> I know this topic has been discussed before, but the answers given only raise more questions, so I am deciding to create a new post.

And yet you asked the same question again instead of the 'more questions' than this raised. Shouldn't you have asked about those?

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to understand how declaration happens in Java. Java is a statically-typed language, once we declare a variable, we can't change the data type of our variable after. Let's look up an examples:

1. **long myLong = 3_000_000_000;**

Integral types(byte,short,int,long) are "int" by default. The differences are sizes(byte<short<int<long).

When we declare a variable we're saying to java that "myLong" variable's type should be long(which is int but longer size). And after we're trying to equalize with "3_000_000_000"(Literal) which is int BUT int's max value is 3,147,483,647 so it's bigger. That's why we should write "L or l" to the end of the literal. After adding "l", now, our literal is long and we can equalize with declared long "myLong". => long myLong = 3_000_000_000l;

2. **int myInt = 300L; => (Error will appears)**

In this example our literal(300L) is long. As I mentioned before long's size is bigger than other integral types. When we delete "L" from end of the literal, "300" will be int.

3. Here is another example for FLoat and Double :

   **float myFloat = 5.5; (Error)
   float myFloat = 5.5F; (Correct version)**

Float and Double are "double" by default. The difference is, double bigger than float. myFloat is "float" in the begining, 5.5 is double so error will appear that we can't equalize. That is why we should add "F or f" to the end of the 5.5. We can use "D or d" for double but it's up on us, it's not necessary because there's no bigger floating type than double.

*Hope it's clear :)*